# fixed x axis in DC js rowChart?

Tags: axis, dc.js, crossfilter

With DC js, trying to set rowChart with fixed X axis of 0-100. However draws it as one single line?

[image: .rowChart xAxis issue]

I set .elasticX(false) and looks like above.
Setting to true makes it look correct, but X axis is elastic obviously.

Version is 2.1.0-dev after changing from 1.7.0 which gave same result.

Following JS looks like:

```
day_chart.width(180)
    .height(180)
    .margins({ top: 0, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 20 })
    .dimension(dayOfWeek)
    .group(dayOfWeekGroup)
    .valueAccessor(function (d) {
        return d.value.Percent;
    })
    // assign colors to each value in the x scale domain
    .ordinalColors(['#3182bd', '#6baed6', '#9ecae1', '#c6dbef', '#dadaeb'])
    .label(function (d) {
        return d.key.split('.')[1];
    })
    // title sets the row text
    .title(function (d) {
        return TooltipOcc(d.key.split('.')[1], d.value.Percent);
    })
    .elasticX(false)
    .x(d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 100]))
    .xAxis().ticks(4)
;
```

html is basic div with id. chart is dc.css and col-md-5 is bootstrap.css

```
<div id="day-chart" class="chart col-md-5">
    <div class="title">Day of Week</div>
</div>
```

Chrome inspector shows that the root space is 180 at least, but something happening internally missing something?

Hopeful it will just be some some placing mistake I made with the JS. Have tried things like placing the `.x(` at different points, removing the `.xAxis`.

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: it looks like you have some sort of composite key, since you are doing `d.key.split('.')[1]` - do you also need a key accessor with `d.key.split('.')[0]`?

Comment: I'm running into the same issue. Not using a composite key

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the domain manually did the trick for me (as per [dc.js forum thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dc-js-user-group/zg_MgogXs2Y))

```
 day_chart.x(d3.scale.linear().range([0,(day_chart.width()-50)]).domain([0,100]));
 day_chart.xAxis().scale(day_chart.x());
```

Comment: I was meaning to answer with link to the dc.js google forum group, I think that thread specifically, which answers this issue, thanks.

Comment: Just to be clear, it's the x scale range that needs to be set? The domain was already set in the code in the question.

Comment: It's worth reiterating that `elasticX` must also be `false` as shown in the original question, otherwise the chart will stretch the bars so that the largest bar appears as if 100% when its value may not be.

Answer (score 0):

I do have the same problem with dc.js row chart.

- crossfilter data normally large, So scroll will hide the x axis
- Visually the axis is out of focus, its difficult to understand the scale

**solution**

1.Create the dc.js row chart with crossfilter data

2.Draw external x axis by using row chart reference

```
// Dataset A 
  var datasetA = [{"Subject":"s1","Name":"A","Mark":"50"},{"Subject":"s2","Name":"B","Mark":"40"},{"Subject":"s3","Name":"C","Mark":"40"},{"Subject":"s4","Name":"A","Mark":"50"},{"Subject":"s5","Name":"B","Mark":"40"},{"Subject":"s6","Name":"C","Mark":"40"},{"Subject":"s7","Name":"A","Mark":"50"},{"Subject":"s8","Name":"B","Mark":"40"},{"Subject":"s9","Name":"C","Mark":"40"}];

    // Initialization of crossfilter for the datasetA
    var CFA = crossfilter(datasetA);
    // Creating the dimension
    subject_DA = CFA.dimension(function(d){ return d.Subject; });
    // Creating the chart 
    subjectAChart = dc.rowChart("#subjectA");
    // Creating the group
    subject_AG = subject_DA.group();
    // subject Chart
    subjectAChart
  .width(550).height(300)
  .margins({top: 5, left: 10, right: 10, bottom: 0})
  .dimension(subject_DA)
  .group(subject_AG)
  .gap(2)
  .title(function(d){  return d.key;})
  .label(function (d) { return d.key; })
  .elasticX(true)
  .colors(d3.scale.category20b())
  .xAxis().ticks(4);

    dc.renderAll();

    var margin = {top: 5, right: 0, bottom: 0, left: 0},
    width = 550 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 35 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var svg = d3.select("#ExtAxis")
    .append("svg:svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.right + margin.left)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append('g')
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
        return "translate("+margin.left+","+margin.top+")";
    });
var xAxis = subjectAChart.xAxis()
svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "extnl-axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(10," + margin.bottom + ")")
    .call(xAxis)
 return xAxis;
```

**[Working Example](https://jsfiddle.net/caravinden/8hpmg5cc/)**